# Distance calculation between the two points in an image using python

Tags: python, image-processing

Here is an image, I need to locate dogs mouth and its tail and i need to find  the distance between dog's tail and it's Mouth using image Procesing (Note: not minimum or spacial distance whole body should be considered).

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'Dog-catches-own-tail_1.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(filename)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
cv2.imwrite('Image.jpg',img)
```

After running the code snippet i am able to get the corner here:

[image]

Comment: Hi @EMKAY, what have you tried so far? Can you show your code?

Comment: I have updated the question please go through it,Thank You @toti08

Comment: If the question is "How do I compute the distance between two points in a bidimensional space?" you get one answer; if the question is "How do I perform convolution on images in order to extract the location of two features, and then determine the distance between their two closest points (or the two centers) in the same image?" you get another answer :) Please post your code.

Comment: As a suggestion: would it be ok to perform clustering on the points selected in the manner you suggested with `img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]`, looking for 2 distinct clusters, and then compute the cosine distance of the centres of the two clusters?

Comment: Thank You @DanielR

Comment: You're welcome. The two retrieved clusters may not correspond to what you intend though, so it will take some tweaking.

Comment: You want to measure how long the dog is from nose to tail? From a 2D image? That is simply not possible! You will need 3D information, because lengths in the 2D projection change with distance to the camera. Parts of the dog closer to the camera will appear larger than parts further away. Parts of the dog that are at an angle to the camera will appear shorter too. You need 3D information.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the content of our discussion in the comments above in the following manner; the computation is done on the bi-dimensional gray matrix that you have extracted. I have assigned zeroes and ones to the values of interest for the matrix being fed to the clusterer, which is in this case KMeans, although it can be replaced with other models as necessary.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'Dog.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(filename)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

gray[dst>0.01*dst.max()] = 1
gray[dst<=0.01*dst.max()] = 0

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
km.fit(gray)
centers = km.cluster_centers_

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances
print(cosine_distances(centers))
```

The output is:

```
[[0.         0.60477114]
 [0.60477114 0.        ]]
```

which is the matrix containing the pair-wise cosine distances of the centers. Further tweaking can be done on the call to .cornerHarris(), and in all truth, it should be checked whether the clusters extracted correspond at least vaguely to the tail and mouth of the dog.
Additionally, generalisation of this method on other images may not be possible. It is unclear what would happen, for example, if the dog were to bite its tail: clusters would very likely be identified in ways unrelated to either the tail, the mouth or both. The more tweaking is done on the code for this particular image, then, the lower the potential for generalisation of this model: it's thus a dog chasing its own tail.